# Applying css to the ticks and line of an axis

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have this in the css (code line 108):

```
.domain {
    fill: 'none';
    stroke-width: 0.7;
    stroke: 'black';
}

.tick {
    fill: 'none';
    stroke-width: 0.7;
    stroke: 'black';
}
```

And this in the javascript (code line 358):

```
// Add y axis with ticks and tick markers
var axisPadding = 2;
var leftAxisGroup = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr({
        transform: 'translate(' + (margin.left - axisPadding) + ',' + (margin.top) + ')',
        id: "yAxisG"
    });
var axisY = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient('left')
    .scale(yScale);
leftAxisGroup.call(axisY);
```

Why is the style not being applied? How do I make sure it is applied?

The full script and context is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/aSgNLb?p=preview

Comment: Does it show as invalid property value? `none` and `black` are keyword values. Placing it in quotes makes it a string. You should use them unquoted.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange add your comment as an answer if you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above CSS could be changed to

```
selector {
    fill: none; /* no quotes */
    stroke: black;  /* no quotes */
}
```

---

Keyword values are *identifiers* and have to be used as they are without quotes. When placed inside quotes these turn into strings which have no meaning under the value definition for their properties. Thus its not parsed as valid by the UA/browser.

**CSS specs**:
[Textual Values](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#textual-values) & [strings](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#strings):

> Identifiers cannot be quoted; otherwise they would be interpreted as strings.

<sub>Footnotes: SVG's fill and stroke properties: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint</sub>